# Multiple methods in replace pattern

Tags: resharper, code-inspection

When I'm trying to write a custom rule in Resharper to split method, I can't save a rule when there are multiple methods in replace pattern  [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5ZMr.png) (It says that method1 is unexpected token, although when I remove method2 everything is OK)

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't possible. The Structural Search and Replace functionality works on code "units", rather than text. So it can replace a single expression or method, but not with multiple methods.